# Conditional pivoting of a pandas Dataframes with duplicate values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Say I have a dataframe which looks like following,

```
df1.head()

ID  NAMES
SAP KASF
SAP HJL
SAP KJOP
LUF LNC1
LUF LNC2
LUF KASF
LUF HJL
```

And I need to reshape the above dataframe as the following, with `NAMES` as rows and the values in column `ID` as columns/headers and fill with 1 or 0.

The values to fill in is based on the matching value in the column `NAME` for each `ID`.

df.head()

```
NAMES SAP LUF
KASF   1   1
HJL    1   1
KJOP   1   0
LNC1   0   1
LNC2   0   1
```

I have tried,

```
df.pivot(index='NAME',columns='ID')
```

And it is throwing,

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Other solution I tried is,

```
( 
  df.T
  .set_axis(["ID"],axis=True, inplace=False)
  .rename_axis('NAME',axis=0)
  .reset_index()
)
```

Which also throwing error due to mismatching vaues for `ID` and `NAME`

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.NAMES,df.ID)` ?

Comment: I have not tried `crosstab`

Comment: There is a crosstab section of the linked duplicate target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: @piRSquared The questions are different unfortunately only the headings. Now I have edited my headings of my question.

Comment: You'll see under what I've labeled question #9 the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you

Comment: you might want to start from here; `pd_df.pivot(index='NAMES', columns='ID', values='ID')` (I could not write my whole answer)

Comment: The solution is: `df.pivot_table(index='NAME',columns='ID',fill_value=0,aggfunc='size')`